# Meteor creating dynamic checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

So i want to create a certain number of check boxes based on the "timesPerWeek" value. The issue I'm having is that when trying to createElement I get Cannot read property 'createElement' of null. Pretty sure it is because the JS renders Before the HTML but i can't figure out what needs to be done to make it so that I can call my function to make the check boxes. This code currently doesn't depend on timesPerweek because I just trying to get a checkbox to show up first.

JS

```
'pie':function()
    {
    var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

        var stuff= progress.createElement('input');
        //var stuff = progress.createElement('input');
        stuff.type = "checkbox";
        stuff.name = "1";
        stuff.value = "set1";
        stuff.id = "stuff";

        var label = progress.createElement('label');
        label.htmlFor = "stuff";
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('pie'));

        progress.appendChild(stuff);
        progress.appendChild(label);

    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="progress" class = "col-md-4">
                progress: {{timesPerWeek}}

                <br/>

                {{pie}}


                </div>
```

I should be able to create elements under progress but it just dies with the error stated above.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this in Meteor is to use an #each helper:

```
<div id="progress">
  {{#each timesPerWeek}}
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox{{@index}}">
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

That should get you several checkboxes to show up.

Comment: Works great the only issue was that timesPerWeek was just a number so I made a function that returned an array